# Detect if JavaFX application is running in jar vs bundled native application

Tags: javafx

As described in https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm#A1324980, you can build self-contained application bundles that appear "native" on the various OS.

Is there a way to determine if the code is run in a self-contained bundle vs code that is run via invoking a jar directly?

JRubyFX applications have a handy ["in_jar?" function](https://github.com/jruby/jrubyfx/blob/a85f8031b5c8dbe0ccf5871a4f765ce42b6577f4/lib/jrubyfx/application.rb#L29) that is pretty hacky, but pretty convenient.